# What does The input is reflected inside a tag parameter between double quotes mean?

Tags: php, xss

A recent scan of [Acunetix](https://www.acunetix.com/) has shown some [vulnerability](https://www.trojanmart.com/verif.php?afficher_forgot_password=Oui%22sTYLe=%27acu:Expre/**/SSion(Afih(9717))%27bad=%22&lang_abbreviation=en&membre=) on one of my pages. I tried reproducing it but i can not find any vulnerability. The so called vulnerably is titled **The input is reflected inside a tag parameter between double quotes mean**.

The scan gives me the following result for my [page](https://www.trojanmart.com/verif.php?afficher_forgot_password=Oui%22sTYLe=%27acu:Expre/**/SSion(Afih(9717))%27bad=%22&lang_abbreviation=en&membre=).

```
verif.php
Details URL encoded GET input afficher_forgot_password was set to **Oui"sTYLe='acu:Expre/**/SSion(Afih(9717))'bad="**
The input is reflected inside a tag parameter between double quotes.

Request headersGET /verif.php?afficher_forgot_password=Oui"sTYLe='acu:Expre/**/SSion(Afih(9717))'bad="&lang_abbreviation=en&membre= HTTP/1.1
 Connection: keep-aliveCookie: PHPSESSID=feef28e9052ce51f6701e34749ca30ac;lang_abbreviation=enAccept: */*Accept-Encoding: gzip, User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, likeGecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36
```

Here is a [direct link](https://www.trojanmart.com/verif.php?afficher_forgot_password=Oui%22sTYLe=%27acu:Expre/**/SSion(Afih(9717))%27bad=%22&lang_abbreviation=en&membre=) that reproduces the so called vulnerability but I do not see any vulnerability on the page.  what does The input is reflected inside a tag parameter between double quotes mean ?

Comment: It looks like a false possitive

Comment: Do you have spare credentials?.I dont wanna sign up

Comment: If you want code reviewed for vulnerabilities, please actually post code to review.

Comment: I would guess (not followed any links) that their input: `Oui"sTYLe='acu:Expre/**/SSion(Afih(9717))'bad="` is being rendered inside something like `<element attr="value">` and thus could be parsed as `<element attr="Oui" sTYLe='acu:Expre/**/SSion(Afih(9717))' bad="">`.

Comment: I checked your site, it is reflected on a lot of different occasions, but the main questions after getting a result like this is, can you actually take advantage of it.

Comment: @RaimondsLiepiņš How can I take Advantage of it please ?

Comment: @VipulNair There is no need to sign up to see the code in the Html source code

Comment: @ManOfGod This is a good starting point https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Reflected_Cross_site_scripting_(OTG-INPVAL-001)

Comment: @RaimondsLiepiņš Thank you very much this is actually very helpful

Comment: Cross-posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275251/what-does-the-input-is-reflected-inside-a-tag-parameter-between-double-quotes-me

Answer (score 1):

## What happened?

The vulnerability scanner thinks that it found a possible reflective XSS or HTML injection vulnerability in the page.

When it injected `Oui"sTYLe='acu:Expre/**/SSion(Afih(9717))'bad="` as a GET request parameter, the page rendered with the following element in it:

```
<a href="https://trojanmart.com/SSionAfih9717" title="Français " class=" ">...</a>
```

Part of the content (`SSionAfih9717`) matched the injected data.

## Should you be concerned?

It depends. Tests like this may often be a false positive, as there are many different scenarios where user-input text may be reflected in the page in a non-harmful way.

It looks like the test was trying to inject a HTML attribute named `bad` into whatever element contained the data, but the word "bad" doesn't appear anywhere in the resultant HTML. I believe a successful attempt may have looked something like this:

```
<a href="https://trojanmart.com/SSionAfih9717" bad= title="Français " class=" ">...</a>
```

Note how the attribute `bad` appears after `href`. This could be used by an attacker to inject arbitrary JavaScript or manipulate the page in other ways.

In your particular case, you don't seem to be affected by the test, and it can likely be considered a false positive. That said, there may be other scenarios you are vulnerable to, as this is just one test of many possible. That said, if the request could completely replace the `href` value instead of being added at the end, it could be used to target `javascript:` URIs or other domains in the attacker's control.

## How to fix it?

If you were really vulnerable to this, you would want to follow best practices outlined in the [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet Rule #5](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#rule-5---url-escape-before-inserting-untrusted-data-into-html-url-parameter-values):

> RULE #5 - URL Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML URL
>   Parameter Values
>
> Rule #5 is for when you want to put untrusted data into HTTP GET
>   parameter value.

```
<a href="http://www.somesite.com?test=...ESCAPE UNTRUSTED DATA BEFORE PUTTING HERE...">link</a >
```

> Except for alphanumeric characters, escape
>   all characters with ASCII values less than 256 with the %HH escaping
>   format. Including untrusted data in data: URLs should not be allowed
>   as there is no good way to disable attacks with escaping to prevent
>   switching out of the URL.
>
> All attributes should be quoted. Unquoted attributes can be broken out
>   of with many characters including [space] % * + , - / ; < = > ^ and |.
>   Note that entity encoding is useless in this context.
>
> WARNING: Do not encode complete or relative URL's with URL encoding!
>   If untrusted input is meant to be placed into href, src or other
>   URL-based attributes, it should be validated to make sure it does not
>   point to an unexpected protocol, especially javascript links. URL's
>   should then be encoded based on the context of display like any other
>   piece of data. For example, user driven URL's in HREF links should be
>   attribute encoded.
>
> For example:

```
String userURL = request.getParameter( "userURL" )
boolean isValidURL = Validator.IsValidURL(userURL, 255); 
if (isValidURL) {  
    <a href="<%=encoder.encodeForHTMLAttribute(userURL)%>">link</a>
}
```

Comment: Can you please give me the same thing in Php ? I am a Php Programmer